# ¿Por qué mi relación Muchos a Muchos no funciona en Doctrine con Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

Tengo una relación Muchos a Muchos definida del siguiente modo:

**Las dos tablas relacionadas**:

```
CREATE TABLE `homily` (
  `homilyID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `homily` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`homilyID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `liturgy` (
  `liturgyID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timeFK` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `typeFK` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `week` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `colorFK` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`liturgyID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `timeFK` (`timeFK`,`typeFK`,`week`,`day`),
  KEY `colorFK` (`colorFK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Y una tabla intermedia que maneja la relación Muchos a Muchos:

```
CREATE TABLE `liturgy_homily_join` (
  `liturgyFK` int NOT NULL,
  `homilyFK` int NOT NULL,
  `theme` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb3_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`liturgyFK`,`homilyFK`),
  KEY `homilyFK` (`homilyFK`),
  CONSTRAINT `liturgy_homily_join_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`liturgyFK`) REFERENCES `liturgy` (`liturgyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `liturgy_homily_join_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`homilyFK`) REFERENCES `homily` (`homilyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Ahora yo quiero consultar a mi tabla `liturgy` con un criterio y obtener todas la filas de `homily` que estén relacionadas.

Para ello he intentado expresar **una relación Muchos a Muchos Unidireccional en `Liturgy`**, [tal y como explica la documentación aquí](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.0/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). La clase queda así:

#### `Liturgy`

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyRepository::class)]
class Liturgy
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name:"liturgyID")]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"timeFK")]
    private ?int $timeFK = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $week = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $day = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"typeFK")]
    private ?int $typeFK = null;

    #[JoinTable(name: 'liturgy_homily_join')]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'liturgyFK', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[InverseJoinColumn(name: 'homilyFK', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: Homily::class)]

    public ?Collection $homilies=null;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->$homilies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getHomilies(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->homilies;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...

}
```

También he intentado **una relación Muchos a Muchos Bidireccional**, [tal y como explica la documentación aquí](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.0/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

En este caso las clases quedan así:

#### `Liturgy`

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyRepository::class)]
class Liturgy
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name:"liturgyID")]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"timeFK")]
    private ?int $timeFK = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $week = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $day = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"typeFK")]
    private ?int $typeFK = null;
/*
    #[JoinTable(name: 'liturgy_homily_join')]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'liturgyFK', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[InverseJoinColumn(name: 'homilyFK', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: Homily::class)]
*/

    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: Homily::class, inversedBy: 'liturgies')]
    #[JoinTable(name: 'liturgy_homily_join')]
    public ?Collection $homilies=null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$homilies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getHomilies(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->homilies;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLiturgyID(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setLiturgyID(int $liturgyID): static
    {
        $this->id = $liturgyID;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTimeFK(): ?int
    {
        return $this->timeFK;
    }

    public function setTimeFK(int $timeFK): static
    {
        $this->timeFK = $timeFK;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getWeek(): ?int
    {
        return $this->week;
    }

    public function setWeek(int $week): static
    {
        $this->week = $week;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDay(): ?int
    {
        return $this->day;
    }

    public function setDay(int $day): static
    {
        $this->day = $day;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypeFK(): ?int
    {
        return $this->typeFK;
    }

    public function setTypeFK(int $typeFK): static
    {
        $this->typeFK = $typeFK;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

#### `Homily`

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\HomilyRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: HomilyRepository::class)]
class Homily
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name:'homilyID')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $homily = null;

    #[ManyToMany(targetEntity: Liturgy::class, mappedBy: 'homilies')]
    private Collection $liturgies;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->liturgies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getHomily(): ?string
    {
        return $this->homily;
    }

    public function setHomily(string $homily): static
    {
        $this->homily = $homily;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Mi problema es que en ninguno de los dos casos el código funciona. Asumiendo este código en `LiturgyRepository`:

```
public function findHomily(string $time,string $week,string $day,string $cycle): ?array
 {
     $timeFK=$this->timeAssoc[$time] ?? null;
     $day=$this->dayAssoc[$day] ?? null;
     $cycle=$this->cycleAssoc[$cycle] ?? null;
     $qb= $this->createQueryBuilder('liturgy')
     ->andWhere('liturgy.id > 0')

         /* quitamos criterios de parámetros por el momento*/
         ->setMaxResults(5)
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult()
     ;
     dd($qb);
     return $qb;
 }
```

Si es que no entendí mal, si la relación funciona, yo debería tener en la propiedad `homilies` una lista de objetos `Homily`, pero siempre obtengo `null`, como se puede ver en el debug:

```
  0 => App\Entity\Liturgy {#651 ▼
    -id: 1
    -timeFK: 1
    -week: 1
    -day: 1
    -name: "Domingo I de Adviento (Año A)."
    -typeFK: 1
    +homilies: null
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Liturgy {#649 ▼
    -id: 2
    -timeFK: 1
    -week: 2
    -day: 1
    -name: "Domingo II de Adviento (Año A)."
    -typeFK: 1
    +homilies: null
```

Aclaro que no es un problema con los datos, las tablas tienen registros coincidentes en esas relaciones. Por ejemplo la consulta:

```
select 
    h.homilyID 
from liturgy l 
inner join liturgy_homily_join j 
    on l.liturgyID=j.liturgyFK 
inner join homily h 
    on j.homilyFK=h.homilyID 
where 
    l.liturgyID=1;
```

Me arroja todas las filas que cumplen la relación:

```
+----------+
| homilyID |
+----------+
|     1987 |
|     1989 |
|     1990 |
|     ...  |
+----------+
```

¿Alguien puede decirme cuál es mi error al implementar las relaciones?

---

### EDICIÓN

[Según este post en SymfonyCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/complex-many-to-many) en Symfony no es posible una relación Muchos a Muchos si la tabla asociativa posee otras columnas aparte de los IDs que relacionan las tablas. Es mi caso, dado que la tabla `liturgy_homily_join` tiene una columna extra que es `theme`. Para resolverlo, habría que crear en la entidad de la tabla asociativa relaciones `ManyToOne` con cada una de las llaves foráneas.

Haciendo eso, las clases quedarían así, pero tampoco funciona.

#### `Liturgy`

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyRepository::class)]
class Liturgy
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name:"liturgyID")]
    public ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"timeFK")]
    private ?int $timeFK = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $week = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT)]
    private ?int $day = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 200)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::SMALLINT, name:"typeFK")]
    private ?int $typeFK = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'liturgyFK', targetEntity: LiturgyHomily::class)]
    public Collection $liturgies;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->liturgies = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getLiturgies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->liturgies;
    }

    public function addLiturgies(LiturgyHomily $liturgies): self
    {
        if (!$this->liturgies->contains($liturgies)) {
            $this->liturgies[] = $liturgies;
            $liturgies->setLiturgy($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLiturgyFK(): Collection
    {
        return $this->liturgyFK;
    }
    public function addLiturgyFK(LiturgyHomily $liturgyFK): self
    {
        if (!$this->liturgyFK->contains($liturgyFK)) {
            $this->liturgyFK[] = $liturgyFK;
            $liturgyFK->setLiturgyFK($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...

}
```

#### `LiturgyHomily`

Esta es la entidad de la tabla asociativa:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyHomilyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Table(name:"liturgy_homily_join")]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyHomilyRepository::class)]
class LiturgyHomily
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(name:'liturgyFK')]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Liturgy::class, inversedBy: 'liturgies')]
    public ?int $liturgyFK = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(name:'homilyFK')]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Homily::class)]

    private ?int $homilyFK = null;

    public function getLiturgyFK(): ?int
    {
        return $this->liturgyFK;
    }

    public function setLiturgyFK(int $liturgyFK): static
    {
        $this->liturgyFK = $liturgyFK;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHomilyFK(): ?int
    {
        return $this->homilyFK;
    }

    public function setHomilyFK(int $homilyFK): static
    {
        $this->homilyFK = $homilyFK;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

El debug de la respuesta, sigue siendo una colección vacía:

```
 0 => 
App\Entity\Liturgy {#650 ▼
    +id: 1
    -timeFK: 1
    -week: 1
    -day: 1
    -name: "Domingo I de Adviento (Año A)."
    -typeFK: 1
    +liturgies: 
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#711 ▼
      #collection: 
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#659 ▼
        -elements: []
      }
      #initialized: false
      -snapshot: []
      -owner: 
App\Entity\Liturgy {#650}
      -association: 
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToManyAssociationMapping {#745 …}
      -backRefFieldName: "liturgyFK"
      -isDirty: false
      -em: 
ContainerM8dkhgs\EntityManagerGhostEbeb667 {#329 …12}
      -typeClass: 
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#623 …}
    }
  }
```

Comment: Segun entiendo debería crear 3 entities: `Liturgy_Homily` (1), la cual debe tener una propiedad `liturgy` con relación `ManyToOne` a `Liturgy` (2)  y otra propiedad `homily` con relación `ManyToOne` a `Homily` (3). Después en la entity `Liturgy` una propiedad `homilies` relación `OneToMany` a `Liturgy_Homily` y en `Homily` una propiedad `liturgies` relación `OneToMany` a `Liturgy_Homily`.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos. Yo tengo creada esa entidad, pero sin indicar ninguna relación. La doc (dos enlaces de más arriba) no dice nada al respecto. En el ejemplo ellos usan una tabla `users_groups` que en mi caso sería la tabla `liturgy_homily_join`, pero no explican que haya que hacer nada en ese entidad. De todos modos, intento lo que comentas y te cuento.

Comment: @Marcos he hecho varios tipos de intentos y no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: @Marcos he agregado una **Edición** al final de la pregunta, incluyendo la clase de entidad para la tabla asociativa.

Comment: Me parece que ahora el problema es de "lazy load", Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26891658/3791844). Más info: [Symfony > Fetching Related Objects](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects)

Comment: Ah... en la entity `Liturgy` ¿no debería ser `$homilies` en lugar de `$liturgies`?

Comment: @Marcos, en la relación, desde `Liturgy` no se conoce a `Homily`. Es en `LiturgyHomily` donde están los IDs de `Homily` así como los IDs de `Liturgy`. Probé con un fetch `EAGER` pero tampoco funciona. En algunas respuestas he visto además que aunque funcione, este tipo de asociaciones producen múltiples consultas a la BD afectando el rendimiento y recomiendan algo que se llama *Hydration*, [ver por ejemplo esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936812/5587982). Voy a intentar por esa vía, a ver si funciona.

Comment: Con respecto a la relaciones, entiendo que desde una `Liturgy` esperas obtener es el listado de `homilies` relacionados a la misma (_y por ende, todo lo relacionado a esta_). Por eso te señalaba que el nombre de la propiedad no es correcto. Con respecto al rendimiento, si... por eso mismo, dichos datos no se "pre-cargan" a menos que los recuperes explicitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así considero que deberías definir tus entities y sus propiedades:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyRepository::class)]
class Liturgy
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'liturgyID', type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 250)]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: LiturgyHomily::class, mappedBy: 'liturgy')]
    private $homilies;

    /* ... codigo ... */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->homilies = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addHomily(Homily $homily)
    {
        if ($this->homilies->contains($homily)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->homilies[] = $homily;
        $homily->addLiturgy($this);
    }

    public function removeHomily(Homily $homily)
    {
        if (!$this->homilies->contains($homily)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->homilies->removeElement($homily);
        $homily->removeLiturgy($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection|Homily[]
     */
    public function getHomilies()
    {
        return $this->homilies;
    }
}
```

```php
#[ORM\Table(name:"homily")]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: HomilyRepository::class)]
class Homily
{

    /* codigo anterior */

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: LiturgyHomily::class, mappedBy: 'homily')]
    private $liturgies;

    /* codigo posterior */
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LiturgyHomilyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'liturgy_homily_join')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LiturgyHomilyRepository::class)]
class LiturgyHomily
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Liturgy::class, inversedBy: 'homlies')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'liturgyFK', referencedColumnName: 'liturgyID')]
    private $liturgy;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Homily::class, inversedBy: 'liturgies')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'homilyFK', referencedColumnName: 'homilyID')]
    private $homily;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $theme = null;

    public function getTheme(): ?string
    {
        return $this->theme;
    }

    public function setTheme(string $theme)
    {
        $this->theme = $theme;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLiturgy()
    {
        return $this->liturgy;
    }

    public function setLiturgy($liturgy)
    {
        $this->liturgy = $liturgy;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHomily()
    {
        return $this->homily;
    }

    public function setHomily($homily)
    {
        $this->homily = $homily;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Y en algún controller podes por ejemplo hacer:

```php
class AppController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/check')]
    public function check()
    {
        $liturgy = $this->liturgyRepository->find(1);
        $liturgy->getHomilies()->toArray();
        dd($liturgy);

        return '!';
    }
```

Comment: Marcos muchas gracias. Es así como debían quedar las relaciones. Otro error que estaba cometiendo era en la consulta, pues no estaba poniendo los `join` correctamente. Así funciona: `$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')->select('l')->addSelect('j')->innerJoin('l.liturgies', 'j')->innerJoin('j.homilies', 'h')->where('l.id= :id')->setParameter('id', $id)->getQuery()->getResult();` Los resultados se muestran correctamente, sólo que en el depurador aparece que hace una consulta por cada fila. Supongo que debo optimizar con Hydrator y/o usar un DTO para construir un solo objeto.